# How do I paste from my clipboard to a string in javascript for Adobe Illustrator script?

Tags: javascript, json, adobe, copy-paste, adobe-illustrator

I need to be able to paste the data in my clipboard into a string in my JavaScript code for an Illustrator script. so far every way I have tried pastes from the clipboard into the actual illustrator file as a text box and not implemented in my code. when the code reads the where the string should be to make a file name, it is set as undefined. is there a way to paste a string without it showing up in the actual file and will be defined in my code?

I have tried App.paste() which just pastes the content somewhere on the file as a block of text. window.clipBoardData says window is undefined. JSON parse and stringify, JSON is undefined. navigator.clipBoardData, navigator is undefined, Clipboard.clipBoardData, Clipboard is undefined.

```
 var Clipboard = {};

    var params= /*Clipboard data to be pasted here*/ 
    "accountName:BigCompany, jobNumber: 8675309";

    var KeyVal = params.split(",");

    var i;
    for (i in KeyVal) {
    KeyVal[i] = KeyVal[i].split(":");
    Clipboard[KeyVal[i][0]]=KeyVal[i][1];
    }

    var folder = new Folder(
      "~/desktop/" + Clipboard.accountName + " " + 
Clipboard.jobNumber);

    folder.create();
```

basically every way I've tried the data comes back as undefined.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot read the text (json) file directly with your code? If you must use the clipboard, you may have to paste the text in your document, put it in a variable and delete the pasted object.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad the reason I cannot read the file directly is because Adobe Illustrator does not recognize JSON and cannot run its functions (parse and stringify) we are using the clipboard in order to copy the data from SalesForce we need to and using that to pull up certain templates and name files.

Comment: I was able to use a JSON api from [https://cdnjs.com/libraries/json2] and then used `#include 'json2.min.js'` and I was able to JSON.parse no problem. I ended up doing a prompt and pasting the data in there, however that leaves a lot of room for user error and bugs. does anyone know of a way i could do that without needing user input? i tried a clipboard API but it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use a JSON api from https://cdnjs.com/libraries/json2 and then used `#include 'json2.min.js'` and I was able to JSON.parse no problem. I ended up doing a prompt and pasting the data in there, however that leaves a lot of room for user error and bugs.